# Can I get start and stop time stamps of executed Linux shell commands?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I run a project build command which has a long execution period. I run it when I go to sleep. Is there some Linux system mechanism that logs the command duration in bash?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the environment you're running this in?  If you've got a shell handy I'd think subbing in  `{ date; doit; date; }` wherever your build command `doit` is would do the job.

Comment: I have three commands to execute with _sudo_. Every commands has long execution time so for every other command excpt the firs one I should type the password again. And I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [`time`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_time.htm) you are searching for? Just prepend the `time` command before the command to be executed:

```
time build_cmd
```

Output looks like:

```
real    0m0.153s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
```

where `real` is the total time the command takes too run, `user` the amount of time spent in userland code and `sys` the time spent in kernel code.

Comment: For those using MacOS, this command is working also in MacOS.

Comment: Sure it is, since it is a bash builtin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get fancy, you can use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) to do your build. It can build any type of project, and not just Java projects. One of the plugins is the [Timestamper](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Timestamper) which will add a time stamp to each execution line of your build. Plus, Jenkins will always tell you (with or without this plugin) how long the build took.

There are lots of advantages of using a CI server for builds, even if you don't use it for continuous integration. (i.e., you either spawn the builds manually, or at a certain time of day).

You can also use the `time` command as pointed out by [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20250743/368630), or write a tiny shell script to print out a timestamp before and after the build:

```
date
build_cmd
date
```

Answer (score 1):

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), as proposed by @DavidV. is a very complete tool to automate and manage build processes, while the `time` command, when prefixing the build command, will tell you exactly how much time the build process took, as proposed by @hek2mgl.

But assume you do not want to install Jenkins, and you forgot to type `time`, and you have started your command already, you can use either of the following trick:

- look at the creation time of the first and latest target, or
- you can also, while the building command is running, typing the `date` command blindly across the output of the building process. It will be buffered and executed when the process terminates. Combine that with the use of [$HISTTIMEFORMAT](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-history-display-date-time/) and you have a pretty good idea of how much the process took.